IMEI check shows different phone model
I have a Google Pixel 5 and wanted to check compatibility with a (US) carrier by my IMEI. The website said that my IMEI is not compatible but that the Pixel 5 is. I wondered, checked my IMEI on https://www.imei.info/ and the website claims that my phone is an (old) Astro Mobicel phone.
How can that be? Do I need to be concerned? So far, I have never had any issues.
(I checked that there is no typo in the IMEI)
